# Renewing developers Cert & APN certificate iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios-provisioning

Our Developer `Cert & Push Notification` Cert both are about to expire. We renewed developer Cert & created a new `Push notification Cert`, updated provisioning profile and submitted to App Store.
If we update new `SSL cert` on our server, will `APN` stop working on App versions signed with old Profile (for users who doesn't update App).

Do we need to keep sending `APN` with two `SSL` from Server till the time most of Users update new version of App.

Answer (score 2):

When your APNS certificate is expired your server is unable to send any notifications. The push notification certificate is not directly  linked to an app.

When you update you APNS certificate all version of the that had pushnotification will receive the notifications again. There is no need to update the app for this.

Comment: I thought that indirect relation of Push certificate effects App also.
As SSL that we use on Server is combination of developer Cert and Push Cert and we have have updated both now.

thanks for the clarification

Comment: but what if i create a new push certf instead of renewing the older one.. with a new key value pair in the certf now old version of my app won't receive the push right?

Comment: No, the you can just renew your push certificate without updating the app.

Answer (score 0):

Once your app is live, then after this if your certificate expires, and you renew that certificate, now your application's APNS will run as usual till you upgrade its new version.

For testing purpose you just need to refresh the provisioning provide after renewing the certificate rest will be done.